# Does apply works according to the rolling update policy?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I know about several ways to perform rolling update of deployment. But do either `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` or `kubectl apply -k ...` update deployment according to the rolling update policy of a new version of deployment or an old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will, with one note :

> Note: A Deployment's rollout is triggered if and only if the
> Deployment's Pod template (that is, .spec.template) is changed, for
> example if the labels or container images of the template are updated.
> Other updates, such as scaling the Deployment, do not trigger a
> rollout.

Reference : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment

For example, you can see the events section of a deployment update after updating the nginx image and running `kubectl apply -f nginx-deploy.yml` :

```
...
NewReplicaSet:   nginx-deployment-559d658b74 (3/3 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  112s  deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5 to 3
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  44s   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set nginx-deployment-559d658b74 to 1
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  20s   deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5 to 2
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  20s   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set nginx-deployment-559d658b74 to 2
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  19s   deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5 to 1
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  19s   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set nginx-deployment-559d658b74 to 3
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  18s   deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5 to 0
$ kubectl get deploy
NAME               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-deployment   3/3     3            3           114s
```

Comment: Could you provide a link for this quote?

Comment: Yep, I edited the answer to add it as reference